# Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "journal3/template/journal3/product_card.twig" is not defined

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, journal

I am upgrading OpenCart Journal to theme 3. Here is the error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "journal3/template/journal3/product_card.twig" is not defined in "journal3/template/journal3/module/products.twig" at line 8. in /home/malakand/public_html/projects/maria-collection/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ArrayLoader.php:70 Stack trace: #0 /home/malakand/public_html/projects/maria-collection/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(299): Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader->getCacheKey('journal3/templa...') #1 /home/malakand/public_html/projects/maria-collection/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(381): Twig\Environment->getTemplateClass('journal3/templa...') #2 /home/malakand/public_html/projects/maria-collection/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(333): Twig\Environment->loadTemplate('journal3/templa...', NULL) #3 /home/malakand/public_html/projects/maria-collection/system/cache/template/0f/0fa7ae2a63aba5ee049a7722e7b80499adaf2cf124c5f3d9fc1d4f53e51dfee2.php(392): Twig\Template->loadTemplate('journal3/templa...', 'journal3/templa...', 8) #4 /home in /home/malakand/public_html/projects/maria-collection/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ArrayLoader.php on line 70
```

I am upgrading opencart from 2 to 3.0.3.7 and journal theme to latest 3.0.37

This error display when I import the backup for journal theme #11.
Admin Panel show success message but website front end display this error.